# Как установить свой BorderBrush при фокусировки на textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть вопросик, как можно поменять бордэрбраш при фокусировки и наведении на текстбокс. Скорее всего работа с триггерами МаусОн или IsFocused? От примерчиков кода не отказался бы, спасибо)

**Обновление**

```
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxTest">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="LightYellow" />
                <Setter Property="Control.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="Aquamarine" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Работает только FontWeight... -_-

Comment: Попробуйте указать `TargetType` для вашего стиля, и использовать внутри свойства прямо, без `Control.`. Может быть, это укажет на проблему.

Comment: VladD, я попробовал, такая же тема... Если я не указываю сам свой Foreground например, то тогда стиль работает. А если я укажу свой параметр, допустим Red, а стиль должен менять его на LightYellow, то не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готово, может кому-то пригодится!

```
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Border x:Name="TextBoreder" >
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="TextBoreder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1D5D96"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```